# Show a specific image on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I am trying to get a div to show when a picture is clicked. This div should contain the clicked picture only larger. I can't get this to work though. I've tried a lot of different things and now I hope someone can help me out or give me some pointers.

First I have my html image, which is generated in a php while loop:

```
<img src='".$picsarray[$picsfrom]."' class='gallerythumbnail'>
```

Then I have my CSS for the div I want to be shown on click of the previous image:

```
#showimagediv {
    display: none;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: -300px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #f00;
    z-index: 6;
}
```

And last I have some Jquery code I tried to make:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(\"#gallerythumbnail\").click(function( event ) {
        $(\".showimagediv\").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

I know I can get the address of the clicked image be using this line:

```
$(this).attr('src')
```

I don't know how to use it in a div, shown when an image is clicked

I hope someone understands what I mean and can help me in the right direction.

Comment: Why is your jQuery escaped?

Comment: your CSS has **ID** `#showimagediv` (which is wrong if you have more of them) --- while you use **CLASS**  `$(".showimagediv").show();` in your jQuery

Comment: oh, that's because it was a part of a php script. Is that wrong? And I can see that my question has been voted down, did I write something wrong or ?

Comment: Additionally there's no need to escape `\"` than you need to explain where's exactly that DIV, is it one or many etc etc. Be more precise if you want a fast and precise answer

Comment: I don't know why it's been down-voted, probably cause you missed some details... like how looks the returned image URL and the part you're interested in etc etc

Comment: Ok, i got the div to show onclick now. The div should contain a picture (a bigger version of the one being clicked)

Comment: Ok, i got the div to show onclick now.. What i want to do is to get the "showimagediv" div to show when an image (in a php loop) has been clicked. This div should contain a bigger version of the clicked image. How can i do that in the Jquery script? Can the content of the div be changed according to which image thumpnail that has been clicked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the source from the thumbnail and create a new image to be inserted into the DIV where you're trying to display the clicked image :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.gallerythumbnail').on('click', function() {
        var img = $('<img />', {
                      src     : this.src,
                      'class' : 'fullImage'
                  });

        $('.showimagediv').html(img).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to resize the image when we are populating it in a div? currently the image that is getting displayed on the div is really small, basically the size of the thumbnail.

Comment: @AnitaMathew - Sure, the class `fullImage` is added to the full image, so just resize it with CSS.

Comment: @adeneo can you have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54530797/how-to-resize-the-image-when-the-source-of-the-image-is-a-thumbnail-image. The image is loosing its clarity when zooming in..very blurry

Answer (score 1):

> *Then I have my css for the div I want to be showed on click of the **previous** image*

if it's correct what you said, **previous one** is the image, that means the DIV is `.next()` to it!

use class for your DIV in your **CSS**:

```
.showimagediv {
```

jQuery

```
$(function() { // DOM ready shorthand

    $(".gallerythumbnail").click(function() {
          $(this).next('.showimagediv').show(); // or you want .toggle() ?
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your CSS code `#showimagediv`. **#** stands for ID attribute.
Your jQuery code uses `.showimagediv`. **.** stands for CLASS attribute.

So first thing you should decide wether that showimagediv is an ID or a DIV and than correct your CSS or your jQuery.

Than, put your img tag inside a  so it becomes 'clickable'. href="#" means nothing will happen when you click it.

```
<a href="#" id="image">
    <img src='".$picsarray[$picsfrom]."' class='gallerythumbnail'>
</a>
```

And change your jQuery function to this (use div.showimagediv if it is a class attribute or div#showimagediv if it is an id attribute):

```
$(function() {
    $("a#image").click(function() {
        $("div.showimagediv").css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

So when you click the image inside the link, it will change the display value from **none** to **block**. This will not toggle, it will show once and not hide again.

If you need to toggle you need to control that inside the jQuery function, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("a#image").click(function() {
        var actualDivDisplay = $("div.showimagediv").css("display");
        var newDivDisplay = "";

        if (actualDivDisplay == "none") {
            newDivDisplay = "block";
        } else {
            newDivDisplay = "none";
        }

        $("div.showimagediv").css("display", newDivDisplay);
    });
});
```