# Wordpress - Show an image when clicked

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, onclick, slideshow

I have made this page:

http://vasikaridis.gr/index2.php/?page_id=21725

At the left you can see a vertical slider. These are posts. And the thumbnail is the post's featured image.

At the right side, you can see a div which has as a background-image (css) the url of the **last** post from the left slider.

All I want is when someone clicks a thumbnail, to change the background-image src from the right div,  to that clicked image.

Is this possible? Cause I have no idea how to fix this.

Thanks in advance!

Vagelis

EDIT: The url of the featured image is fetched with this code:

```
<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'thumbnail') ); ?>
```

So then I do this:

```
<div id="fbg" style="background:url('<?php echo $url ?>') center center no-repeat;"></div>
```

But how am I suppose to make the code dynamically change the `$url` when I click the thumbnail?

See full code here: http://pastebin.com/18G0Pa9P

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708439/show-a-specific-image-on-click

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Kirito/y0g5rd1e/

Comment: @Roman Not really. :/ This works, but I do not know the url of the images. In your example the url is given manually. I want the url to be fetched dynamically.

Comment: So you want to get the url which is called when you clicked on one of the images on the left side?

Comment: fetched from where? try saving the image url in an extra attribute and swap it when needed

Comment: LuisP.A. - It's close to what I want, but I get the images from wp_query. How can this be used with Wordpress?

Comment: @Roman yes! this is what i want. I want to get the $url to change "on the fly" when someone clicks the image from the left side.

Comment: @CerlinBoss - Yes this works great in my mind.  I just don't know how to "store" temporary the img urls in an attribute and then call those images whenever i want. I don't know how to write that code.

Comment: Sorry that it took so long, I wasn't here for a moment. Have a look at this fiddle. Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/Kirito/a18cueg7/4/

Comment: add the part of code which prints the post in left hand side.

Comment: @Roman this fiddle is only usefull if i have two images, or if i enter the images manually. Please read other comments too, this has to bynamic. I cannot know the amount of images (thumbnails).

Comment: I saw your solution. I totally missunderstood you. Sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that have the same issue:

```
    <script>
(function($){
$('.img').click(function(){
  var image = $(this).attr('src');
  document.getElementById("finalimg").src=image;
});
})(jQuery);
    </script>
```

The above script says that whenever the thumbnail `(.img)` is clicked, then take that thumbnail's src and store it to the variable 'image'. Then go to the image with id finalimg and replace its src with the url stored in the variable 'image'.

So everything works as intended.

Thanks everyone for your time and help!