# How to resize the image when the source of the image is a thumbnail image

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using a carousel to display images as thumbnail after fetching their path from a database. Now when I click on a particular image , I want the image to populate the image-div , but I don't want the image to   loose its clarity when resizing. 
When I use the following code the image being displayed is same as the thumbnail i.e it is not getting resized. How to go about this?

html:
css:

```
 .rs{

        width: 700px;
        height:1020px;
    }
```

The div in which I want to display the image:

```
 <div id=" IMGDIV"  class="img-container"  style= "visibility:visible; ">
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" Class="rs" runat="server" name="Image1"  style='height: 1020px; width:700px' src='<%# resizeAndConvertToBase64(Eval("image_path").ToString(),1020,700) %>' />

                                </div>
```

The carousel:

```
  <td class="auto-style5">
  <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
  <asp:Repeater ID="rptImages" runat="server"   >
  <ItemTemplate>
     <li>
        <img id="Image4" alt="" style='height: 90px; width:80px' src='<%# resizeAndConvertToBase64(Eval("image_path").ToString(),90,80) %>' class="thumbnailimg" />

   </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jcarousel/0.2.8/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#mycarousel').jcarousel();
});
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thumbnailimg').on('click', function () {

        var img = $('<img />', {
            src: this.src,

            'class': 'rs'
        });

        $('.img-container').html(img).show();
});
    });
    </script>
```

code behind:

```
protected string resizeAndConvertToBase64(string imageDirectory, int newWidth, int newHeight)
    {
        Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        System.Drawing.Image srcImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imageDirectory);

        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            gr.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            gr.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            gr.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            gr.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight));

        }
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        newImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        var base64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        return "data:image/gif;base64," + base64Data;
    }
```